# jQuery Tags-Input with Rails4 / Simple_form

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, simple-form, jquery-tags-input

I'm Using **Rails 4** with **[Simple_form](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form)** and **[acts_as_taggable](https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on)**.

> I'm Trying to implement the **[jQuery Tags Input](https://github.com/xoxco/jQuery-Tags-Input#instructions)** for my Tags (atcs_as_taggable).

The HTML for the **Tags_input** is:

```
   <input name="tagsinput" class="tagsinput" value="School,Teacher,Colleague" />
```

which translates in **Simple_form**:

```
   <%= f.input :tag_list, input_html: { class: "tagsinput "} %>
```

Tags that i entered before the change are properly displayed in the Edit/form, but NEW tags arent Saved.

The JS for my Tags_input is simple:

```
   $(".tagsinput").tagsInput({
    width: '300px'
   });
```

What am i missing ?

Comment: Did you solve this query?

Comment: The answer from @rmagnum2002 covered me !

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As for me, this plugin is not the best that you could use.

I would go with

1. **Chosen** http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/ or
2. **jQuery Tokeninput** http://loopj.com/jquery-tokeninput/.

Used to like 2nd more, but Chosen is a great plugin that is my favorite now.

As for implementing them in rails:

**Chosen**

**Gemfile**

```
group :assets do
  gem 'chosen-rails'
end
```

**app/assets/javascripts/application.js**

```
//= require chosen-jquery
```

**app/assets/stylesheets/application.css**

```
*= require chosen
```

**app/assets/javascripts/questions.js.coffee**

```
jQuery ->
  $('#question_tags_ids').chosen()
```

**questions/_form.html.erb**

```
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :tag_ids, "Tags" %><br />
  <%= f.collection_select :tag_ids, Tag.order(:name), :id, :name, {}, {multiple: true} %>
</div>
```

---

**jQuery Tokeninput**

**app/assets/javascripts/application.js**

```
//= require jquery.tokeninput
```

**app/assets/stylesheets/application.css**

```
*= require token-input-facebook
```

**app/assets/javascripts/questions.js.coffee**

```
jQuery ->
  $('#question_tag_tokens').tokenInput '/tags.json'
    theme: 'facebook'
    prePopulate: $('#question_tag_tokens').data('load')
```

**questions/_form.html.erb**

```
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :tag_tokens, "Tags" %><br />
  <%= f.text_field :tag_tokens, data: {load: @question.tags} %>
</div>
```

**models/question.rb**

```
attr_accessible :name, :tag_tokens
attr_reader :tag_tokens

def tag_tokens=(tokens)
  self.tag_ids = Tag.ids_from_tokens(tokens)
end
```

**tags_controller.rb**

```
def index
  @tags = Tag.order(:name)
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.json { render json: @tags.tokens(params[:q]) }
  end
end
```

**models/tag.rb**

```
def self.tokens(query)
  tags = where("name like ?", "%#{query}%")
  if tags.empty?
    [{id: "<<<#{query}>>>", name: "New: \"#{query}\""}]
  else
    tags
  end
end

def self.ids_from_tokens(tokens)
  tokens.gsub!(/<<<(.+?)>>>/) { create!(name: $1).id }
  tokens.split(',')
end
```

Comment: Could you join me in Chat ? http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38054/the-mini-johns-rails-tags-input-room